# invalid sid vk api auth.signup

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Отправляю запрос на *api.vk.com* и получаю ответ

```
{
  "error": {
    "error_code": 1113,
    "error_msg": "Invalid sid",
    "request_params": [
      {
        "key": "client_id",
        "value": "2274003"
      },
      {
        "key": "client_secret",
        "value": "*******"
      },
      {
        "key": "v",
        "value": "5.313"
      },
      {
        "key": "first_name",
        "value": "Лариса"
      },
      {
        "key": "last_name",
        "value": "Подгорнов"
      },
      {
        "key": "birthday",
        "value": "10.09.1999"
      },
      {
        "key": "phone",
        "value": "48733369903"
      },
      {
        "key": "sid",
        "value": "407012560369"
      },
      {
        "key": "captcha",
        "value": "qxmuddn"
      },
      {
        "key": "sex",
        "value": "1"
      },
      {
        "key": "method",
        "value": "auth.signup"
      },
      {
        "key": "oauth",
        "value": "1"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```